# Is it possible to set module.exports as a setter/getter javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, getter-setter, accessor

In file a.js

```js
// a.js
let a = 1

Object.defineProperty(module, "exports", {
  get() {
    return a
  },
  set(v) {
    a += 1
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
})
```

In file b.js

```js
// b.js
const a = require("./a")
console.log(a) // 1
a = 2 // a should now be 3
// Throws "Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."
```

Is there some way to do this? (use setter on something I `require`'d)

Comment: So a little explanation of what is happening here. When you require a, you are getting the Value returned by the getter, not the getter object itself Becuase it is a getter, hence the returned object is a number, not an object. You are also assigning the value to a Constant, which cant be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! But also, No.

While this technically IS doable, you then run into the issue of not being able to access the setter once it is required, as it will call the Getter and return the value when require()'d. So the getter/setter functionality is Only accessible via the source file, with the getter supplying a response to require.